# Creating dynamic threadpool based on server resources

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an application where it has around 10 threads in a pool and each thread runs for 10 seconds and a new one is added to pool. Is there an efficient way to write dynamic thread pool that increases number of threads based on server resources available ? When server is idle or not utilized much, it has to increase number of threads(pool size should become 15) and when server is busy, it has to shrink down to 10 threads.

Comment: The question needs some more details in order for anyone to really answer. Can you define what is "server" in your context ? Is this "server" something you are developing ? It makes sense to do your own thread pooling when you are also developing the server. Otherwise you are better off utilizing the "servers" thread pool than take this thread pooling matter on your own. Please provide more background.

Comment: By "Server" I mean the machine where my application runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When server is idle or not utilized much, it has to increase number of threads(pool size should become 15) and when server is busy, it has to shrink down to 10 threads.

The simplest solution is to lower the priority of the process or the threads.

By lowering the priority, your process will tend to only use the CPU if there is free CPU to use. It won't actually stop but will get slower, the lower you make the priority when the machine is busy.

When the machine is not busy, even the lowest process will get as much CPU as it wants.